# Parsing a complex JSON data returned by API in javascript EDITED : It worked with PHP!CODE ADDED

Tags: javascript, php, json

EDITED WITH PHP CODE :this works

```
$json_url = "https://httpapi.com/api/products/reseller-price.json?auth-userid";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $json_url);

$str = curl_exec($ch);

$ar = json_decode($str,true);


echo $ar['domcno'][0]['pricing']['addnewdomain'][1];
```

the following javascript doesnt works !

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

var url = "https://httpapi.com/api/products/reseller-price.json?5&api-key=";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()                        
{ 
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)                              
    {   
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);           
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET",URL,true);
xmhttp.send();


function myFunction(response)                                                                               
{
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var i;
    var out = "<table>";
```

**now from here I've to parse the json data and then display it in a table**

***Json data sample looks like this:***

```
{"dotpoker":{"privacy-protection":"0.0","0":{"pricing":{"addtransferdomain":{"1":"2494.69"},"restoredomain":{"1":"6653.79"},"addnewdomain":{"1":"2494.69"},"renewdomain":{"1":"2494.69"}},"category":{"category3":{"name":"NA","quantity":"0.00"},"category2":{"name":"NA","quantity":"0.00"},"category1":{"name":"receipts","quantity":"0.00"},"category6":{"name":"NA","quantity":"0.00"},"category5":{"name":"NA","quantity":"0.00"},"category4":{"name":"NA","quantity":"0.00"}}}},"dottires":{"privacy-protection":"0.0","0":{"pricing":{"addtransferdomain":{"1":"5475.39"},"restoredomain":{"1":"9634.39"},"addnewdomain":{"1":"5475.39"},"renewdomain":{"1":"5475.39"}},"category":{"category3":{"name":"NA","quantity":"0.00"},"category2":{"name":"NA","quantity":"0.00"},"category1":{"name":"receipts","quantity":"0.00"},"category6":{"name":"NA","quantity":"0.00"},"category5":{"name":"NA","quantity":"0.00"},"category4":{"name":"NA","quantity":"0.00"}}}}
```

from the above I've to only show in html table on webpage the domain name : "`dotpoker`" and price of `"addtransferdomain" , "renewdomain" , "addnewdomain"` , so four columns and some selected domain names.

Please help me and give guidance, I've gone though so many json queries and code samples but I am still stuck.

Thanks

P.S If there is way to do this in PHP then also let me know

Also ,when I parsed it on http://json.parser.online.fr/ it shows me a structure, if anyone can check this and guide me as to how to fetch the required data.

Comment: You need to define "doesn't work." What do you expect to happen? What happens instead? Are there errors displayed in the console?

Comment: Hello, there arent any errors displayed .I'd expected for a table to be displayed using the JSON data fetched by the API call. Even when I tried to display a static table in script it wasnt getting displayed, but when I tried to display the same in <div> element it was displayed. That means the script wasnt running. Do you have any other solution? Its been 2 days that I am hunting for a solution that time only one replied, unfortunately it still didnt work,yesterday after long thought I tried out PHP code and it worked. And please read my complete question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've completely reworked my answer based on your examples / current methods. No need to go the DataTables route if you are not familiar with JS.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<h1>Customers</h1>
<div id="id01"></div>

<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://httpapi.com/api/products/reseller-price.json?5&api-key=";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var key;

    //add table header
    var out = "<table style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">";
    out += "<thead><Domain><th>Add/Transfer Domain</th><th>Restore Domain</th><th>Add New Domain</th><th>Renew Domain</th></thead><tbody>";

    //loop through json keys and grab data
    for(key in arr) {
      if(arr.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

        out += "<tr><td>" +
        key +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[key][0].pricing.addtransferdomain[1] +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[key][0].pricing.restoredomain[1] +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[key][0].pricing.addnewdomain[1] +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[key][0].pricing.renewdomain[1] +
        "</td></tr>";

      }
    }

    out += "</tbody></table>";

    //put out string in defined div
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply but I am unable to understand as I am very new to web programming javascript/php. As you can see in the question I've used the API call in <script> part of my main html page, how to move ahead from here..

Comment: Also which lib I'll have to download?

Comment: Ok,the json I provided above is just a sample copy pasted from the huge json file . Please explain the columns part in your reply. The json sample I pasted is for" dotpoker", "dottires" similarly there are n domains , and for each I have to display a register price "addnewdomain" , renew "renewdomain" and transfer price "addtransferdomain"

Comment: I've to display these details in table format ,http://manage.resellerclub.com/kb/answer/1029 here the structure is mentioned , as I am new its getting difficult for me to parse these huge JSON file and print only certain values.

Comment: Also If I am supposed to use DataTables or jquery , from where I will have to download these files?

Comment: I was referring to this w3 example http://www.w3schools.com/json/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_server_sql to code for the above

Comment: The webpage on which I have to display this html table fetching data from API is ready , only at particular position I will have to make changes ,place this table. I am not understanding as to how to go about the whole problem.

Comment: Updated my answer to be more in line with your current methods - simply use the JSON object indexes to retrieve each data object. If you have problems, perhaps you could try `var str = JSON.stringify(response);
    var arr = JSON.parse(str);` in place of the JSON.parse line.

Comment: Really appreciate your replies, I will try as you have suggested in the above code and revert back for any further queries. Also as a beginner I want to ask if its ok to place 
script like above at the end of html just before end of body? or should it be at the start?   Also I've placed the div element in code at the place on webpage where I want the table to appear.

Comment: Right now I am waiting for the IP to be whitelisted , but when I'd run the page the heading RESELLER PRICING gets displayed right on top on left side.

Comment: Also, if you can tell me why count++ is used?

Comment: I've revised the code slightly - Removed count variable (not needed) and removed some testing code that is not required functionality. My example shows you that the JS must be within <script> tags, but can be placed within the <body> (or <head>) element of the page. The location of the table will be at the <div id="id-1"> element, as you say.

Comment: Earlier when when I used the h1 and div ,the reseller pricing heading used to get displayed right at the top left corner. Now while running it I used <tr><td="shadow class" as used previously and the heading gets displayed exactly where I wanted ,but still the table isnt getting displayed. S

Comment: Is it because of space on the page that it refuses to display? is there some more formatting I should do?

Comment: "<thead><Domain> " this should be <thead><th>Domain</th or <thead><tr><th>Domain</th>.. right? is <tr> necessary?

Comment: whatever is in the <script> part its not getting run, I tried to put a sample table in div and it got printed, but then when I put the table in the <script> it doesnt get printed.

Comment: Hi, it worked for me in PHP. So, thanks for all your help with regards to javascript, I dont know why the script wasnt working. I am still looking out for it , but for now I will make use of PHP because it finally displays the required result.

Comment: No problem - I'm unsure on the specifics of your environment to say why it wasn't executing, but I'm glad you got it working in the end - apologies for the late reply!

Comment: No prob, it works fine in php. Though I wonder why it didnt work in javascript,is it because the code was making a httprequest for a URL with "https" OR is it because the URL had additional info like the auth id and key that may be why it wasnt processing the request. Anyways, really grateful for your replies that motivated me more to work on the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
public DataTable JsonStringToDataTable(string jsonString)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string[] jsonStringArray = Regex.Split(jsonString.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", ""), "},{");
        List<string> ColumnsName = new List<string>();
        foreach (string jSA in jsonStringArray)
        {
            string[] jsonStringData = Regex.Split(jSA.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", ""), ",");
            foreach (string ColumnsNameData in jsonStringData)
            {
                try
                {
                    int idx = ColumnsNameData.IndexOf(":");
                    string ColumnsNameString = ColumnsNameData.Substring(0, idx - 1).Replace("\"", "");
                    if (!ColumnsName.Contains(ColumnsNameString))
                    {
                        ColumnsName.Add(ColumnsNameString);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception(string.Format("Error Parsing Column Name : {0}", ColumnsNameData));
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        foreach (string AddColumnName in ColumnsName)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(AddColumnName);
        }
        foreach (string jSA in jsonStringArray)
        {
            string[] RowData = Regex.Split(jSA.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", ""), ",");
            DataRow nr = dt.NewRow();
            foreach (string rowData in RowData)
            {
                try
                {
                    int idx = rowData.IndexOf(":");
                    string RowColumns = rowData.Substring(0, idx - 1).Replace("\"", "");
                    string RowDataString = rowData.Substring(idx + 1).Replace("\"", "");
                    nr[RowColumns] = RowDataString;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(nr);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: can you explain what it does? I am new to javascript

Comment: pasting large blocks of code with no explanation is not helpful