# Getting all elements on a json schema using php

Tags: php, json, foreach, schema

I really need help on this one.

I have the following Json Schema:

```
{
    "url": "http://www.google.com",
    "bodySchema": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "SKU": {
                "sync": "True",
                "mapTo": "SKU",
                "type": "string"
            },
            "WareHouseId": {
                "sync": "False",
                "mapTo": "",
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "Stock": {
                "sync": "True",
                "mapTo": "Stock",
                "type": "integer"
            }
        },
        "required": {
            "0": "SKU",
            "1": "Stock"
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to retrieve all elements and check if they are required or not,

On the first part (Getting all elements)

What I'm doing is:

```
foreach ($this->methods as $data) {
    if(!empty($data['bodySchema']->properties)){
    }
}
```

But my problem is that I have no way to get the SKU, WarehouseID or Stock, because it's not a key nor anything of the kind.

For my second issue what I was thinking, was to put all required as string and do a loop through them, but if there is any alternative would be glad to know.

Comment: Refer to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36759525/parsing-a-complex-json-data-returned-by-api-in-javascript-edited-it-worked-wit/36765367?noredirect=1#comment61190261_36765367

Comment: Thanks @GBnewbie but I had that part already solved out and working, I had issues getting the keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the properties out with a simple loop:

```
foreach ($data->bodySchema->properties as $key => $value) {
    // ..
}
```

If you want to add the required field to the results from above, you can do it like so:

```
foreach ($data->bodySchema->required as $required) {
    $data->bodySchema->properties->$required->required = true;
}
```

[Example with objects](https://eval.in/570424) or [with arrays](https://eval.in/570423).

Comment: Thanks it worked the first part with a small change: foreach ($data['bodySchema']->properties as $key => $value) {

about the required I want to put on bold the properties that are required

Comment: In that case if you used my second example you could then look the properties again and do `if ($property->required) { // make it bold }`

Comment: what is $property on your first example?

Comment: solved using foreach ($data['bodySchema']->required as $required) { and an if inside, but I don't like that is doing a loop for each property